# Can't find approles in the returned JWT

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal, json-web-token

I noticed something while working with Azure AD.

Having specified on client's manifest the approles as application , when I generate a token using both **UserAssertion** and **ClientCredentials**, I can't find approles in the returned JWT payload. That doesn't happen if I generate a token using only **ClientCredentials**, where indeed there's also approles returned

Is that normal or I'm missing something? 
Thanks in advance

### Update

I'm gonna try to explain the scenario

Here's the app manifest:
`{ 
   "allowedMemberTypes": 
          [ "Application" ], 
   "displayName": "Protocollo", 
   "id": "some GUID", 
   "isEnabled": true, 
   "description": "some Descr", 
   "value": "Proto" 
}`

I have three apps: app a, app b and app c. 
App B has the application role (see manifest above), and the user logs in in app a. 
App c needs the username of the logged user in app a. 
When app b generates the token for app c using both UserAssertion and ClientCredentials (as i explained before) I can't find app b role in the returned jwt. That doesn't happen if I only use client ClientCredentials

Comment: Could you explain your scenarios a bit more? You have some app A which specifies appRoles? Then you have some app B to which you have granted those app permissions (appRoles)? And now you are fetching a token for app B to call app A?

Comment: @juunas I see i've been unclear here. I have three apps: app a, app b and app c. App B has the application role, and the user logs in in app a. App c needs the username of the logged user in app a. When app b generates the token for app c using both **UserAssertion** and **ClientCredentials** (as i explained before) I can't find app b role in the returned jwt. that doesn't happen if I only use client **ClientCredentials**

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring application roles for your application ? The scenario you describe (using UserAssertion and ClientCredentials) is using Delegated User Identity with OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of :
[image]

A user has authenticated on a native application, and this native application needs to call a web API. Azure AD issues a JWT access token to call the web API. If the web API needs to call another downstream web API, it can use the on-behalf-of flow to delegate the user’s identity and authenticate to the second-tier web API. So only `delegate permission` involved in access token in this scenario .

The scenario (use client ClientCredentials) is using Application Identity with OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant ,Azure AD authenticates the application and returns a JWT access token that is used to call the web API . Application roles involved in access token in this scenario .

Comment: I configured the app's manifest as follows: 
`{
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "displayName": "Protocollo",
      "id": "some GUID",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "some Descr",
      "value": "Proto"
    } 
`

Is there any scenario that doesn't involve the use of groups and doesn't break my requisites?

Comment: What do you mean by " involve the use of groups and doesn't break my requisites?" . Do you wan to restrict access base on the role of login user ? Then you need to set user role on app a , app a get the user role and restrict access to related api function in app b .